# How to center Bootstrap SVG Icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap SVG Icon without bootstrap.

https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/arrow-clockwise/

See this code:

```
<span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z"/>
  <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z"/>
</svg>
  </span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;">My Text 1</span>
</span>

<span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z"/>
  <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z"/>
</svg>
  </span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;">My Text 2</span>
</span>
```

My question: how do I vertical align the text to the center of SVG icon next to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use flexbox for this. Something like:

```html
<span style="display: inline-flex; gap: 5px; align-items: center;">
  <span style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z"/>
      <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z"/>
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span>My Text 2</span>
</span>

<span style="display: inline-flex; gap: 5px; align-items: center;">
  <span style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z"/>
      <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z"/>
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span>My Text 2</span>
</span>
```

Comment: If I replace 16 with other size such as 24, it will not align

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to match the height of the SVG with the text, and change the layout a bit. Try this:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 18 18" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z" />
        <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z" />
    </svg>
    <span>My Text 1</span>
</div>
```

Just included 1, you can produce the other similarly.

Comment: If I replace 18 with other size such as 24, it will not align

Comment: It won't, if you want the 24, then you'll have to increase the height of the span containing the text and then also bring the text in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed you're using Bootstrap too so used some util classes from it & have wrapped the items in a `hstack` element to spread them out. Seems ok with smaller icons but to me looks slightly off as icons get larger.

```
<div class="hstack gap-4">
  <div>
    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z" />
        <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z" />
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle">My Text 1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z" />
        <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z" />
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle">My Text 2</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z" />
        <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z" />
      </svg>
    </span>

    <span class="d-inline-block align-middle">My Text 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/themelizeme/pen/eYEGBMq

Comment: OP is not using Bootstrap (written in first line).

Comment: You're right, missed that my bad!